# Aspx page has content of size in MB while calling

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, devexpress

I have an issue. On calling a page "treatmentreq.aspx?key=&refno=0452-85198&user=admin" downloads a page with 12mb of contents. attached is the screenshot below.
[Click here to go to image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKcOl.png)

How can I solve this issue as it takes 8-10 mintues to load the page?
Note: I have been using devexpress as reporting tool.

Comment: Since it is ASPX, check what you store in ViewState, which is being serialized in a hidden field and transferred to the client's browser.

Comment: Yeah, i found it. it has a large amount of input type "hidden" and name is "_VIEWSTATE". How do we handle this issue?

Comment: Do not store so many (useless) data in ViewState. That is done like this: `ViewState["DataID"] = someData`... So just don't overuse it.

Comment: Thank you very much @Matyas , I have added EnableViewState="false" within Page directive in page itself. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

disabling the view state can solve this problem. It can be done by adding EnableViewState="false" in the page directive itself.